# A complete cyrillic opentype font

Tags: fonts, opentype

I am currently looking for a cyrillic font (for russian typewritting). It must be an opentype font usable with lualatex and fontspec, and must be complete : roman, italic, bold, small caps, superiors letters and figures, in serif and sans serif. For all I know, Libertinus is very close, but it lacks cyrillic small caps and superior cyrillic letters. Does a more complete font exist?

Comment: I’m sorry I don’t have an answer to your question, but I wanted to thank you for mentioning Libertinus; I was also looking for a font that has a lot of Unicode characters and combining diacritics.